# Looking for advice on fixing an existing vinyl fence

Tags: fence, vinyl, gate-post

My wife and I were lucky enough to buy our first house last year and have discovered some problems with the fencing installed by a previous owner. One side of the front of the house has vinyl fencing in a straight line that is freestanding and not attached to any other fencing or structure. It has a large gate and a side gate.

```
House ||==||Side||Double  Double||1" ||Neighbor's
Front ||==||Gate||Gate A  Gate B||Gap||Fencing
```

The vinyl posts are seated only in gravel (no concrete) and I have no idea how deep. I am assuming not deep enough as the posts shift with the wind and are no long straight up and down. I am also assuming, but fairly certain, that the gates are too heavy for the two freestanding posts on either side of the double gate. When I reinforced the base of the posts, the vinyl post began to noticeably bend above that point. In addition, the siding appears to have been glued into the rails.

We are working with a tight budget at the moment and so we are hoping to repurpose as much of the existing material as possible until we can afford to replace the entire section. My plan is to put properly installed (gravel base, cement pier, and buried at least 1/3 total length) pressure treated 4x4s at the location of the existing vinyl posts and them slide them over the top of the wood ones. There seems to be some conflicting opinions online about putting a vinyl sleeve over wood due to it causing rot in the wood.

I am looking for a potentially long term solution to secure the fence so my dog won't escape. I am hoping to keep and reuse as much of the existing design and materials as possible to keep costs down. If there is a better solution or something I might have missed, please help me.

Comment: This could use some pictures.

Comment: This sounds like a mess with multiple problems.  Without pics, any advice would be based on guesses.

Comment: _mumblemumble a picture is worth 1000 ASCII arts mumblemumble..._

Comment: On a more serious note, you indicate that you want to use 4x4 posts then slip the existing vinyl posts over the top. That seems to be a good idea, but that tells me that all you have is a 4x4 vinyl post _cover_, set in gravel (no concrete in sight?), attempting to hold up a gate? If that's true, whoever installed this fence performed some serious magic to get that to stand up and hold a gate in the first place!

Comment: Also, what is your actual question? Your penultimate paragraph sounds like a good plan, but it also doesn't sound like a stop-gap plan - it sounds like a good long term solution. Please [edit] to ask a _specific_ question, also, please take the [tour] and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: FreeMan, I think you are correct and they are in fact vinyl post covers and not vinyl posts themselves.

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing it. Plenty of viny posts are actually posts, for better or worse. I agree, though, that we can't help without more detail and an actual, specific question. Please take the [tour].